# Comparing a list to two other lists with greater/less than - python 3. How do I do it?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm not sure how to approach this, I have two lists that describe two points in 3D space (cube shape) (x1, y1, z1) and (x2, y2, z2), and I want to test if a point is *within* those two specified points (x3, y3, z3). How would I approach this? I'm relatively new at Python and the most simple solution would be appreciated :P .

```
     for bullet in b.bulletlist:  # declaires two points for each bullet in the list of bullets
            pos_bullettip = list(
                map(lambda x: (x[0] + 0.25, x[1] + 0.25, x[2] + 0.25), bullet[0]))
            neg_bullettip = list(
                map(lambda x: (x[0] - 0.25, x[1] - 0.25, x[2] - 0.25), bullet[0]))
            for enemy in e.enemylist:  # Declaires the point that will be tested for, enemy point in this case
                enemypoint = enemy[1]
                # not sure what to here
```

Comment: do you mean test if point3 is __between__ point1 and point2. Three points create triangle with sides which have size A, B, C. If A+B=C or A+C=B or B+C=A then points are on one line. Using [pygame.math.Vector3.distance_to](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector3.distance_to) you can calculate A, B, C.

Comment: @furas - Not necessarily testing if between, but in the cube that point 1 and 2 makes.

Comment: two points can't make cube - they can make only line. You would need 8 points to have cube. If cube is rotated then it can be problem to check point inside cube. Eventually with two points you could create not-rotated cube and then you test `x1 < x3 < x2` and `y1 < y3 < y2` and `z1 < z3 < z2` (if `x1 < x2` and `y1 < y2` and `z1 < z2`)

Answer (score 1):

ok your code looks not about the topic and if im wrong correct me. i understand that you have a quadrangular's 2 corner when you look from z and your right is positive x "bottom-left-back" as p1, "top-right-front" as p2 in cartesian coordinate system like {p1(x,y,z), p2(x1,y1,z1)} and you want to check if p3 in the quadrangular. you can check the x y z planes if p3 grater than p1 and smaller than p2:

```
def ifcovers(p1,p2,p3):
    return p1[0]<=p3[0]<=p2[0] and p1[1]<=p3[1]<=p2[1] and p1[2]<=p3[2]<=p2[2]
```

edit: thnx furas :)
edit1: thnx Kingsley damn math is hard bro :D

Comment: shorter  `return (p1[0]<=p3[0]<=p2[0] and p1[1]<=p3[1]<=p2[1] and p1[2]<=p3[2]<=p2[2])`

Comment: This is a good answer, but it relies on `p1` and `p2` being "top-left-front" and "bottom-right-back" (assuming Z-depth *into* the screen).  As @furas commented against the OP, you may need a more robust definition of the 3D box - or at least manage your point-ordering carefully.

Comment: @JacobLepley what da hell are you doing bro can i see your code :DD:D